# Regex handling zero-length match

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have string with *(asterisk) symbols as an input. String is considered as invalid if it has two consecutive asterisks. But, there is an escape symbol \ (backslash).

For example:

- "**" (invalid)
- "\**" (valid)
- "case**" (invalid)
- "case\**" (valid)
- "*\*" (valid)

I'm on stuck on such regex's which produce incorrect result:

1. `/[^\\]\*\*/` - `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("/[^\\\\]\\*\\*/")`
2. `/([^\\]*?\*\*)|(\*\*)/` - `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("/([^\\\\]*?\\*\\*)|(\\*\\*)/")`.

Also, I've read about greedy, reluctant and possessive quantifies from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

I know that problem is about zero-length matches, but could not produce correct regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a regex, that will only match invalid strings? This should do:

```
"(?<!\\\\)\\*\\*+"
```

It will match two or more asterisks in a row, not preceded by a backslash.

EDIT: `(?<!foo)` thingy is called "negative look-behind". It matches any zero-length place in the string that is not immediately preceded by a region matching the regex inside parentheses ("foo" in this case, or a backslash in yours). 
I had this as `[^\\\\]` at first, which is almost the same thing (in this case), *except* that it matches any *character*, other than a backslash, but not an *absense* of a character, like at the beginning of a string in "**".

There is a good detailed  description of lookarounds (look-behind and look-ahead) as well as a lot of other regex "magic" [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Nah. I am careful enough. I read that your tried something, and it "produced incorrect result". If you have any follow up questions, or need additional help, please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: @tvelykyy Ah. Indeed. Sorry about that. Fixed it now.

Comment: It seems to be working. Need to test on other examples. I would appreciate if you explain this group (?<!\\\\)

Answer (score 2):

Use string.matches method. This returns true for valid strings.

```
String s1 = "case**";
String s2 = "case\\**";
System.out.println(s1.matches("(?=.*(\\\\\\*\\*|\\*\\\\\\*)).*"));
System.out.println(s2.matches("(?=.*(\\\\\\*\\*|\\*\\\\\\*)).*"));
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zM3pD6/4)

Comment: Chosen answer is far more simpler.

Comment: his regex matches all the invalid strings but mine would match all the valid strings. That's the difference.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Nah. To match all valid strings just do `!String.matches(invalidStringPattern)`. :)

Comment: "hack" in the way means op's expected output is different and your's would produce the different output (inverse) when you failed to use the negation operator on very first. I didn't say yours is  a wrong answer  and mine is the correct answer..